# Как установить и работать с Sphinx?

Tags: php, sphinx

Есть ли мануал на русском. в котором бы было показано как устанавливать сфинкс на centos а так же как его применять в php и были бы примеры?

Comment: Лучше с ним не работать :-)

Comment: @Чад бред. Лучше ты сам вряд ли напишешь.

А в чем проблема установки его на centos?

Comment: @Shrek, Да я и не собираюсь. Просто смысла в нём никакого. Умел бы он индексировать по вычисляемым полям. А так сбоку припёка. Размер индекса пипец какой. Грамотная архитектура базы и грамотные родные индексы дадут скорость не меньше. К 4вёртой версии наверное будет уже хорош.

Comment: Ну ты загибаешь. Ты хоть работал с ним?

Ты знаешь за сколько он находит информацию в базе не только mysql а еще и рядом лежащих доков? Нет, ну тогда советую промолчать про "не вижу никакого смысла"

Если твоя база всего на 100метров - то он тебе не нужен, а если есть не 1 десяток Гб - то прости лучше чем сфинкс ты сам не напишешь + он очень тонко настраивается.

Comment: Работал. На вполне многогигобайтной базе. Ну, раздув индексы в 10-20 раз большее самой базы, сложно при этом искать долго. MySQL тоже тонко настраивается, просто мало кто это умеет. Ладно, не буду начинать холи вар, Рад что Ты, @Shrek, столкнулся с той стороны драной кошки, где количество плюсов было больше минусов. Может в применении к php это мяукающее, бородатое скотино соответствует своему историческому положению.

Answer (score 3):

Сама установка вроде как не должна вызывать проблем:

- [Install Sphinx 2.0.4 on CentOS 6.2](http://gadelkareem.com/2012/03/12/install-sphinx-2-0-4-on-centos-6-2/)
- [How do I install Sphinx on a CentOs 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049243/how-do-i-install-sphinx-on-a-centos-5-5)